# DateTime Validation Error

Tags: asp.net, ienumerable

I am not receiving the validation error on form submission, rather it brings up the generic error page set by the controller.

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult Add(Loan loan)
        {
            try
            {
                    _dbLoan.Loans.Add(loan);
                    _dbLoan.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            catch
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

Partial View:

```
<div class="form-group input-group-sm">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeliveryDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DeliveryDate, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Delivery date here  DD-MM-YYYY..." })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeliveryDate)
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class Loan : IValidatableObject
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Instance Variables
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int LoanID { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Select Date")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<ValidationResult> res = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (DeliveryDate < DateTime.Today)
        {
            ValidationResult mss = new ValidationResult("Appointment date must not be in the past. Please try again.");
            res.Add(mss);

        }
        return res;
    }
```

Can anyone help as to why the Validation error is being ignored?
Thanks.

Comment: you have all required plugins for validation ?

Comment: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]  . Please add this at top of the property and see is it works ?

Comment: Thank you Yashveer. I have added this but it does not work.